# Run Python Script (On Network Drive) as Windows Service with NSSM

Tags: python, pywin32, background-service, windows-task-scheduler, nssm

I have followed around 5 tutorials on using `NSSM` to run a `python` script residing on a **network drive**. It creates the service, I can edit the service but when I start the service I get the following error:

`Unexpected status SERVICE_STOPPED in response to START control`

When I try starting the Windows-10 service from Services I get the following error:

[Services error during start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xeng.png)

I have changed the path to the python script from the full network path to a mapped network path and that did not change anything.

I have also tried using Task Scheduler which worked once in a while and was intermittent and I also tried the `pywin32` method as posted [here](http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/) but it fails to start the service as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. On my remote VM it does not allow **Local System Account** to be set as the **Log on**. It required me to add an admin user name and password. It's running now.